# onpropertychange does not trigger when type the first word in IE8

Tags: internet-explorer-8, propertychanged

if give a value to input when bind propertychange event,it will not trigger the first change
`window.onload=function(){
    var textBox = document.createElement("input");
    document.body.appendChild(textBox);
    textBox.value='qw';
    //赋值后立即绑定，IE8输入第一个字符的时候不会触发onpropertychange
    textBox.attachEvent('onpropertychange',function(){
        alert(textBox.value);
    });
};`
e.g.
type "12345"
there's nothing happened when type "1";
how to fixit without setTimeout;

Comment: `// oldValue = elem.value;
                if (browser.ie == 9 || browser.ie == 8) {
                    $(elem).on('focus' + iefx, function() {
                        doc.on('selectionchange' + iefx, setter);
                    }).on('blur' + iefx, function() {
                        doc.off('selectionchange' + iefx, setter);
                    });
                }
                // IE8
                if (browser.ie == 8) {
                    $(elem).on('keyup' + iefx, setter);
                }`

Answer (score 0):

i add keyup event to fix IE8

`if (browser.ie < 10) {
        // 检查是否为可输入元素
        var isInput = function(elem) {
                return elem.nodeName == 'INPUT' || elem.nodeName == 'TEXTAREA';
            },
            iefx = _.uniqueId('.ieinputFixed');
        $.event.special.input = {
            setup: function() {
                if (!isInput(this)) return false;
                var elem = this,
                    oldValue = this.value,
                    setter = function() {
                        if (oldValue !== elem.value) {
                            oldValue = elem.value;
                            $.event.trigger('input', null, elem);
                        }
                    },
                    doc = $(document);
                // oldValue = elem.value;
                if (browser.ie == 9 || browser.ie == 8) {
                    $(elem).on('focus' + iefx, function() {
                        doc.on('selectionchange' + iefx, setter);
                    }).on('blur' + iefx, function() {
                        doc.off('selectionchange' + iefx, setter);
                    });
                }
                // IE8
                if (browser.ie == 8) {
                    $(elem).on('keyup' + iefx, setter);
                }
                //ie6-9
                elem.attachEvent('onpropertychange', $.data(elem, iefx, function(event) {
                    if (event.propertyName.toLowerCase() == "value") {
                        setter();
                    }
                }));
            },
            teardown: function() {
                if (!isInput(this)) return false;
                if (browser.ie == 9 || browser.ie == 8) $.event.remove(this, iefx);
                this.detachEvent('onpropertychange', $.data(this, iefx));
                $.removeData(this, iefx);
            }
        };
    }`